# Jetty only serving static files

Tags: debian, jetty, servlet, gwt, java

For some weird reason I can not get jetty to properly deploy my gwt project.
I have put the war folder in the webapps folder and renamed it to root after that i can start jetty and it recognizes the project and its web.xml.

```
2013-12-03 12:27:49.576:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.6.v20130930
2013-12-03 12:27:49.699:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/spydon/bin/jetty/webapps/] at interval 1
2013-12-03 12:27:50.841:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@321236f4{/,file:/home/spydon/bin/jetty/webapps/root/,AVAILABLE}{/root}
2013-12-03 12:27:50.943:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5f909402{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

But when visiting the page(146.185.176.150:8080/) I can only see the static welcome page. No errors are recorded to the logs.

This is basically my web.xml, except that there is a lot more servlet mappings in the real one.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                                     [89/1588]
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>missionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.mindlevel.server.MissionServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>missionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mindlevel/mission</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Mindlevel.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

It is jetty-9.0.6.v20130930 running on debian 7.0 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, all of the GWT generated files did not make it to the server on deploy. So jetty was working perfectly fine all the time.